# UITableView with processes Load Cached Data - Display Table - Load New Data - Refresh Table

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, caching, refresh, reloaddata

I have a tableview which is made up of a lot of data which I download, to this end it takes some time for the table to display (a second or two).  So what I started to do was cache the data locally, now when the view is displayed it appear nearly instantly - great.

The problem is I then want to go and get a clean set of data and then refresh the table view

1) the UI is blocked and so the cached data is never displayed

2) I am worried that overwriting the cached data while a "reloadData" is happening will cause problems. It seems you cannot reliably test if a table has been displayed (as technically it will never complete).

I am doing it like so;

```
-(void)updateInfo
    [arrayOfItems removeAllObjects]; 
    [self loadItems:useCached];
    [itemTable reloadData];
    if(useCached)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cached data Displayed, now updating");
        useCached = NO;

        [self updateInfo];
    }
}
```

I am wondering if my whole approach is incorrect - any ideas on what is the best practice.

For problem 1 I believe it is a Main Thread issue, however, the above code runs on the background and as far as I understand reloadData is done on the main but it does not draw.  Forcing it to the main does not seem to help either.

For problem 2 I am starting to think that the line [self updateInfo]; should call something else which replaces items in my array rather then clear it.